# Inter-actor communication in akka is guaranteed to be locally FIFO.True or False

Tags: akka

Inter-actor communication in akka is guaranteed to be locally FIFO. Is this statement True or False? Im not sure about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the `mailbox` you chosen for your actor.

By default, in per actorsystem, the messages sent to one actor will be handled one by one according to the sequence you sent to the actor.

But if you choose some special mailbox, e.g. `PriorityMailbox`, things changed, steps as follows:

a) Create a priority mailbox:

```
import akka.dispatch.PriorityGenerator
import akka.dispatch.UnboundedStablePriorityMailbox
import com.typesafe.config.Config

// We inherit, in this case, from UnboundedStablePriorityMailbox
// and seed it with the priority generator
class MyPrioMailbox(settings: ActorSystem.Settings, config: Config)
  extends UnboundedStablePriorityMailbox(
    // Create a new PriorityGenerator, lower prio means more important
    PriorityGenerator {
      // 'highpriority messages should be treated first if possible
      case 'highpriority => 0

      // 'lowpriority messages should be treated last if possible
      case 'lowpriority  => 2

      // PoisonPill when no other left
      case PoisonPill    => 3

      // We default to 1, which is in between high and low
      case otherwise     => 1
    }
)
```

b) Add it to the configuration:

```
prio-dispatcher {
  mailbox-type = "docs.dispatcher.DispatcherDocSpec$MyPrioMailbox"
  //Other dispatcher configuration goes here
}
```

c) And then an example on how you would use it:

```
// We create a new Actor that just prints out what it processes
class Logger extends Actor {
  val log: LoggingAdapter = Logging(context.system, this)

  self ! 'lowpriority
  self ! 'lowpriority
  self ! 'highpriority
  self ! 'pigdog
  self ! 'pigdog2
  self ! 'pigdog3
  self ! 'highpriority
  self ! PoisonPill

  def receive = {
    case x => log.info(x.toString)
  }
}
val a = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Logger], this).withDispatcher(
  "prio-dispatcher"))
```

You will see logs as follows, the message is not first in first out now. But with `default mailbox`, your answer is YES.

```
/*
 * Logs:
 * 'highpriority
 * 'highpriority
 * 'pigdog
 * 'pigdog2
 * 'pigdog3
 * 'lowpriority
 * 'lowpriority
 */
```

You can reference to [Akka document](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/mailboxes.html) for more details.